# generics "specialization" for equal types

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert `Rc<Vec<F>>` into into `Rc<Vec<T>>` where `T` and `F` are numeric types like `u8`, `f32`, `f64`, etc. As the vectors may be quite large, I would like to avoid copying them if `F` and `T` are the same type. I do not manage to find out how to do that. Something like this -- it does not compile as the type comparison `T == F` is invalid:

```rust
fn convert_vec<F: num::NumCast + Copy, T: num::NumCast + Copy>(data: &[F], undef: T) -> Vec<T> {
    data.iter()
        .map(|v| match T::from(*v) {
            Some(x) => x,
            None => undef,
        })
        .collect()
}

fn convert_rc_vec<F: num::NumCast + Copy, T: num::NumCast + Copy>(
    data: &Rc<Vec<F>>,
    undef: T,
) -> anyhow::Result<Rc<Vec<T>>> {
    if (T == F) {        // invalid
        Ok(data.clone()) // invalid
    } else {
        Ok(Rc::new(convert_vec(data, undef)))
    }
}
```

The vector that I need to convert from is the response from a server which first sends the data type (something like "u8", "f32", "f64", ...) and then the actual data. At present, I store the vector with these data in enum like

```rust
pub enum Values {
    UInt8(Rc<Vec<u8>>),
    Float32(Rc<Vec<f32>>),
    Float64(Rc<Vec<f64>>),
    // ...
}
```

At compile time, I do not know in which format the server will send the data, i.e. I do not know `F` in advance. I do know `T` in every case I use it, but `T` might be a different type depending on the use case.

Using specialized functions like `convert_rc_vec_to_f32` it is easy to handle the case where `clone()` is best. But that requires a separate function for each `T` with almost identical text. I am trying to find a more elegant solution than writing a macro or more or less repeating the code 9 times.

Comment: I don't think this is trivially possible. It all boils down to the fact that if you implement a trait for `T where T: SomeTrait` then you cannot specialize it any more for a specific type, because that specific type could at some point implement `SomeTrait` and therefore collide. That's one of the limitations of Rust's type system. There is an [RFC for specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html), but it won't be stabilized any time soon due to major problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to prevent your function from being monomorphized with `T` and `F` being the same type, or even change its behavior in that case. Instead, you should not use it *at all* if it would be monomorphized in that case. This is possible because, if `T` and `F` were the same type, you would know it at compile time, so you could actually simply remove the function call *at all*.

---

It seems that you are actually storing all these vectors into an `enum`, which means you only know the actual type at run-time. But this doesn't mean my suggestion doesn't apply. Typically, if you wanted to get a vec of `f32`, you can do something like

```rust
match data {
    Float32(v) => v,
    Float64(v) => convert_rc_vec(v),
    UInt8(v) => convert_rc_vec(v),
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I extended the question, trying to explain why I do not know `F` at compile time.

Comment: @acfbuerger I edited to show you an example of how you can handle your enum.

Comment: That would require writing a different function for every output type, which is exactly what OP wanted to avoid, according to their question.

Answer (score 0):

If `T` and `F` both have a `'static` lifetime, then you can use [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/struct.TypeId.html) to compare the two types "at runtime":

```rust
if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<F>() {
    Ok(data.clone()) // invalid
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```

However, since this comparison happens "at runtime", the type system still doesn't know that `T == F` inside of this branch. You can use unsafe code to force this "conversion":

```rust
if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<F>() {
    Ok(unsafe {
        // SAFETY: this is sound because `T == F`, so we're
        // just helping the compiler along here, with no actual
        // type conversions
        Rc::<Vec<T>>::from_raw(
            Rc::<Vec<F>>::into_raw(data.clone()) as *const _
        )
    })
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```